# How store additional information about images

Tags: android

I have to write app which will show all images from device and let user write description and rate them with using the ratingbar. I thought i coudl store such information in exif tags but exifinterface is too poor, so coudl you give me some idea how coudl i store such informations?

Comment: ... write an XML file with the same title of your image? Or include the image in an HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do something similar (but not for images), and due to the nature of the app and usability, I used an xml file to store relevant information. Alternatively, you may use a local database to do the same, if there is going to a fair number of images.

If using XML file, perhaps, you may want to consider encryption, if necessary, so not allow access to the contents from outside the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform)

Here is a nice little library to help you out: [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/formatsupport.html)

Answer (score 0):

since u are only storing a tag..  u should use a key value pair using Android Shared preferences

> getSharedPreferences()

each image name with it's date of update makes a unique key and the value wud be the tag the user wants to add..

check out following link for further details

[Android Developers SharedPreferences page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)